# how to set pick value from database in variable using Google apps script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

MySQL table1 structure:

```
id  name  age  status
1   roy    30    1
2   jon    40    0
3   roky   25    1
4   jerin  28    1
```

```
number_row=select * FROM table1 where status=0

for{i=0;i<number_row;i++}
  if (status==0){
    update that row and save in table2 
  }else{
     no update
  } 
}
```

Code: I can't set pick value from database table in variable to apply 
If Else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (status=0){
```

to

```
if (status==0){
```

> =  is assignment
>
> == is equality
>
> === is strict equality